# How to open parquet (binary data type) files in python without getting RAM error?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, parquet

I converted some CSV data to parquet and was able to reduce the storage volume from 2,5 GB to 450 MB. I use following code to open the parquet file:

```
df= pd.read_parquet("PATH/file9.parquet", engine='auto')
```

My problem is that I get the following error while I try to open the parquet file.

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowIOError: Arrow error: Out of memory: malloc of size 2941974336 failed
```

I know that its possible to open big csv files by chunking them as follow:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv("PATH/file9.csv", chunksize=chunksize):
```

It was possible to open smaller parquet files with that line. But I couldn't find any solution for opening big parquet files. Can anyone maybe recommend another data type which is compact as parquet and can be opend without problem? Or how to chunkthe parquet file?

Comment: Please also add the code that yields that error you're seeing.

Comment: Done @AKX but as is said i didnt have problem with opening smaller files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [underlying read call](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_table.html#pyarrow.parquet.read_table) does not support any sort of chunking parameter, so unfortunately no, you can't read a Parquet file in a piecewise way, not with that library anyway.

If you don't need all of the columns, though, you can pass in the `columns=(...)` kwarg.

Comment: alright but why is it possible with read_csv? And which library do you recommend for reading parquet files?

Comment: The `fastparquet` library seems to have something that might help you: https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.ParquetFile.iter_row_groups

Comment: Alright that worked with opening columns but thats not the optimal solution but just for the record, the desired columns can be opened by columns=(["Column1","Column2",...]). Thanks you.